# If input field is empty fill it with random number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, random

I want to fill all empty number fields with a random number.  I can populate all fields with a random number as shown below.

```
    $.each(numberField, function () {
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        ($(this).val(x));
    });
```

But if I try and wrap it around an

```
    if (numberField.val() === "")
```

It doesn't work

What am I doing wrong here? [see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eC48k/)

```
    <input type="number" value="0">
    <input type="number" value="">
    <input type="number" value="4">
    <input type="number" value="5">
    <input type="number" value="">

    var numberField = $('input[type=number]');
    var x = '';
    if (numberField.val() === "") {
        $.each(numberField, function () {
            x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            ($(this).val(x));
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your condition (you are looking if an array is equal to "", which is never the case). You also need to trim the value to check if it is really empty:

```
var numberField = $('input[type=number]');
var x = '';

$.each(numberField, function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) === "") {
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        ($(this).val(x));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

in your example numberField is an array so your code must be like this:

```
var numberField = $('input[type=number]');
var x = '';

    $.each(numberField, function () {
       if ($(this).val() === "") {
          x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
          $(this).val(x);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eC48k/1/).

```
$.each(numberField, function (k, v) {
  if ($(v).val() === "") {
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    ($(v).val(x));
  }
});
```

Take a look at the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) for the jQuery each function.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
var numberField = $('input[type=number]');
var x = '';

$.each(numberField, function () {
    if (this.value === "") { // should check the value inside the loop.. not outside
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        this.value = x;
    }
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eC48k/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
numberField.val()
```

instead, use

```
$(this).val()
```

so ...

```
var numberField = $('input[type=number]');
var x = '';
$.each(numberField, function () {
    alert($(this).val());
    if ($(this).val() === ""){
        x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        ($(this).val(x));
    };
});
```

updated Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/eC48k/

Answer (score 0):

You can match only the fields with no value like this:

```
$('input[type=number][value=""]').each(function () {
        this.value=Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
});
```

Here's the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eC48k/11/).